# PL/SQL errors with CREATE PROCEDURE

Tags: oracle

I need your help, I am going crazy two hours trying to fix the errors of this PL/SQL code. Can someone see the mistakes I have made?

These are the errors I am receiving:

Procedure CHECK_ZIP compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR

---

0/0       PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/103     PLS-00302: component 'state' must be declared
Error at the beginning of the line : 31 nel comando -
BEGIN
check_zip('00914', 'Santurce', 'PR');
END;
Report error -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00905: object STUDENT.CHECK_ZIP is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Here the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_zip (p_zip_code IN zipcode.zip%TYPE, p_city IN zipcode.city%TYPE, p_state IN zipcode."state"%TYPE) AS

v_zip_code zipcode.zip%TYPE;
v_city zipcode.city%TYPE;
v_state zipcode."state"%TYPE;
v_existing_zip zipcode.zip%TYPE;

BEGIN

v_zip_code := p_zip_code;
v_city := p_city;
v_state := p_state;
--

SELECT ZIP
INTO v_existing_zip
FROM ZIPCODE
WHERE ZIP = v_zip_code;
-----
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Il codice ZIP ' || v_zip_code || ' è già presente nel nostro database');

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
INSERT INTO ZIPCOCE (ZIP, CITY, "STATE", CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_DATE)
VALUES (v_zip_code, v_city, v_state, USER, SYSDATE, USER, SYSDATE);

END;
/

--TESTING THE PROCEDURE
BEGIN
check_zip('00914', 'Santurce', 'PR');
END;
/
```

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance

Comment: you have a typo in your exception insert. ZIPCOCE instead of ZIPCODE

Comment: I think that in `v_state zipcode."state"%TYPE;` `"state"` should be uppercased

Comment: "state" doesn't really need to be quoted at all; it is a keyword but not a reserved word. So [it works without quotes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=adae53f2109790d8e17880ea2029d50c) (and with the table name fixed).

Comment: Thank you guys! I solved it °-° I can't believe I lost so much time and couldn't see the mistake, I didn't know about the quotes, it worked well without them! Thank you again ^^

Comment: @AlexanderGechev - [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) explain quoted vs. nonquoted identifiers. (Basically - avoid quoted identifiers if you can.)